# Is there a more efficient way for storing vector<vector<string>> ? C++

Tags: c++, file, vector, ifstream, push-back

The real file I read is about 15.000 kBs. Thus I am not sure whether this is the best way of storing such a data structure.

Here is the code.

```
string line;
ifstream File;
vector<vector<string>> v;
string filename = "meddra.txt";
File.open(filename);

if (File.is_open()) {
    while (getline(File, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        vector<string> row;
        while (getline(ss, line, ',')) {
            row.push_back(line);
        }
        v.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

And here is sample text file:

> CID100000085,CID000010917,C0000729,Abdominal cramps
> CID100000085,CID000010917,C0000737,Abdominal pain
> CID100000085,CID000010917,C0002418,Amblyopia
> CID100000085,CID000010917,C0002871,Anaemia
> CID100000085,CID000010917,C0003123,Anorexia

Thank you for contribution.

Comment: When `v` is of type `vector<vector<string>>`, then `v[c]` is of type `vector<string>`. Thus `v[c][j]` is of type `string`.

Comment: you are forgetting to `push_back` to v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying an empty vector

```
vector<vector<string>> v;
v[c][j].push_back(line);
```

Instead you should do `v.push_back` with a `vector<string>`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a vector of vectors like this:

```
vector<vector<string> v
```

then if you analyze the following instruction:

```
v[c][j].push_back(line);
```

then you are calling a `push_back(line)` method into a string.

**v** is a vector holding vectors of strings

**v[i]** is a vector of strings at index **i**

**v[i][j]** is a string at index **j** of the vector at index **i**

that is the reason of the error

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `v[c][j] = line;` instead of `v[c][j].push_back(line);`. `v[c][j]` returns a `mutable ref` of type string. However `string` does not have `push_back()` method.

And as `v[c][j]` is a `mutable ref` it can be assigned to a new value.